# Set an attribute to method from partial class

Tags: c#, attributes, partial

I have a following class:

```
    public partial class A //file 1
    {
        public int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a+b;
        }
    }
```

How to set an attribute to Sum method from a partial of Class A

```
public partial class A //file 2
{
//Todo
}
```

I have used MetadataTypeAttribute but I can only set to properties. the problem is methods!
Remember that we can not modify partial class in file 1

Comment: You can only add attributes where the method is declared.

Comment: so we can not set it from other partial!